# Bash if-else: Syntax error near unexpected token `else'

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command, wget

I'm trying to write a script that implements a simple web browser using `wget` and `lynx -dump`. I'm stuck with a syntax error when trying to ask the user what to do (`b` to go back or `q` to quit):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Welcome, please do one of the options:
Type an URL
or press b to go BACK to the previuse URL
or press q to QUIT "

read x

if [[ $x = "q" ]]
then
  exit
elif [[ $x = "b" ]]
tail -n urls.txt | wget
else
  $x >> urls.txt
  wget $x
fi
```

Here's what I get when I run  `./browser` and try to just enter `q`:

```
$ ./browser
Welcome, please do one of the options:
Type an URL
or press b to go BACK to the previuse URL
or press q to QUIT
q
./browser: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./browser: line 14: `else'
```

I instead expected it to just accept the command and exit without errors.

Comment: If you want get more answers, you should add the code and the error-message here. Use [edit] and code-formatting. The screenshot isn't the right way asking questions. Learn more in [help].

Comment: Paste code instead of using screenshots and explicitly include your error messages.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I updated your question with the code you had in your screenshot, actual output (the error message you get) and expected output (what you wanted to happen). This is generally a good format for asking questions that you can apply to your next one! :)

Comment: An alternative is using `case $x in ....`.

Answer (score 2):

`elif` needs a `then`

e.g.

```
  if false
  then
      echo in if
  elif true
  then
      echo in elif
  fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    read x

    if [[ $x = "q" ]]
    then
      exit
    elif [[ $x = "b" ]]
    then                    //you missed "then" here
    tail -n urls.txt | wget
    else
      $x >> urls.txt
      wget $x
    fi
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.